# Modeling relation between occurence and schedule for a gym class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, rails-activerecord

I am trying to model the relationship between an occurrence of a class and its schedule. This is what I have:

```
class Schedule < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Has attributes like 
  #  :starts_at (time only, no date)
  #  :repeats_on (weekday name represented as integer)
  #  :type (the type of exercise that will be taught, say Spin, Kickboxing)
  #  :duration
  has_many :occurrences
end  

class Teacher < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :occurrences
end

class Occurrence < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :teacher
  belongs_to :schedule
  # Has attribute
  #  :occurs_on (date only, no time, time comes from schedule reference)
end
```

Now, if I make a change to a "schedule" (say I change the starts_at of the Spin class on Wednesday from 4:30 pm to 5:00 pm), this will then affect all the past occurrences that "belonged to" this "schedule". To avoid this, it seems I need to do this: Whenever the user edits a "schedule", mark the old schedule as inactive, and create a new schedule. That way, only new occurrences will point to this new schedule, and past ones won't be affected.

Is this the right way to model this relationship?

Comment: Can you give a bigger picture on how this will work out in the app? What is a use-case scenario? This will help us to understand how the data should best be structured.

Comment: For example, I don't understand what occurences actually represent and why, when a schedule time gets changed, that occurences become invalid.

Comment: Every day, the gym has a number of classes like Spin, Pilates, etc. This follows a weekly schedule or time-table. For example, Sun 2:00 pm Pilates, 5:00 pm Spin, Mon 5:00 pm Cardio. Now, the manager wants to assign teachers to classes that will be held this month. But the same teacher many not teach all the Monday 2:00 pm classes. So, we need to distinguish between the schedule class (which has no date information, only time and weekday) and the occurrence (which has a specific date and time, and also other attributes like who is teaching the class).

Comment: Now, an occurrence points to a schedule. For example, the Monday Aug 19 2 pm occurrence has a reference to the schedule for Monday 2 pm. If on Aug 20, the schedule for Monday 2 pm is changed so that the start time becomes 3 pm, it should not affect the Aug 19 2 pm class that is pointing to it. It should only affect future occurrences. This is because I don't want to store all the attributes of the schedule like start time, class type, duration etc in the occurrence (since it would be a duplication). Since past occurrences are all pointing to a schedule, I need to be careful when editing it.

Comment: OK now I understand. I think MarsAtomic has a good answer, but I'll give an alternative one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should have 3 classes (Lesson, Schedule and LessonOccurrence) instead of just schedule and occurrence.

```
class Lesson < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Has attributes like
  #  :type (the type of exercise that will be taught, say Spin, Kickboxing)
  has_many :schedules
end

class Schedule < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Has attributes like
  #  :starts_at (time)
  #  :occurs_on (weekday name represented as integer)
  #  :duration
  belongs_to :lesson
  belongs_to :location
end

class LessonOccurrence < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Has attributes like
  #  :date
  #  :start_time
  #  :duration
  belongs_to :lesson
  belongs_to :teacher
  belongs_to :location
end

class Teacher < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :lesson_occurrences
end
```

So a lesson of type "kickboxing" might happen at 3 times in a week so it has three schedule objects. Then, when the week's timetable is created out of lesson_occurrences, 3 lesson_occurrence objects are added to that lesson, each taking its time and duration from each one of the 3 schedule objects.

I can't see any way of avoiding the duplication between time and duration in your situation, but I think like MarsAtomic suggests, you should consider them different sorts of things - schedules hold suggested time and duration, and lesson_occurrences hold actual ones.

Now I think about it, this answer is in essence the same as MarsAtomic's - because you might not gain much out of splitting schedule into lesson and schedule, depending on the rest of the app.

Comment: If I am storing date, start_time, duration already in each occurrence, I may as well store the lesson too, and I no longer need any association between occurrence, schedule, and lesson. This was my concern with MarsAtomic's solution. What do you think of the solution I suggested in my question? That does avoid data duplication.

Comment: You can do it that way, but I don't like it. You would essentially be saying that schedule objects are immutable, other than whether they are active or not. The reason they're immutable is not reflecting the reality it's modelling, but just because of the way underlying things are structured. This makes me uncomfortable, but it doesn't mean it wont work or that it will cause problems.

Comment: I just extended this to include location, which could be another class with room number and capacity, etc. I would refer to it from both schedule and lesson_occurrence. This looks like more duplication, but I still think it would be the way to go because you've got a distinction between the template of suggested things and the actual things themselves.

Comment: Maybe it is because I called it a schedule and it seems wrong to assume a schedule is immutable, since schedules change all the time. If I called it a KlassTemplate instead, would it make more sense? A template is kind of set in stone. Each occurrence is made from a template. We don't want to change this template. We just create new templates that are similar to existing ones and deactivate the old ones.

Comment: but are you going to use it to construct a timetable?

Comment: The more I think about it, the more I prefer the way I've laid it out (without knowing more of your app). If you add enrolements that would be connected to Lesson. If you took a role of who turned up, that would be connected to LessonOccurrence.

Comment: The only reason for the relationship between Lesson and Schedule is so that when you generate new LessonOccurrences it's good to know which schedules you should be generating them from. The distinction between Lesson and LessonOccurrence is needed because some stuff is to do with what happens each time, and other stuff is not time specific.

Comment: The reason why I split Lesson and Schedule is because I think it's better as a one to many relationship (assumption, not knowing what you're modelling) The only stuff that's different at each point in the week it happens is day, time and location. The rest should not be duplicated like that.

Comment: Of course, I'm just describing the way I would do it. If you feel more comfortable with your way, then go ahead with it. I don't see why it wouldn't work.

Comment: Yes, I would need both enrollments and who turned up in the future. Right now, all I need is who is teaching the class occurrence . I am still not convinced that the data duplication is needed. I could handle enrollments to lessons by splitting lesson out of schedule but continuing to have occurrence belong_to schedule. Thanks anyway for all your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You need to denormalize the relationship between Schedule and Occurrence a bit, and edits to Schedule will not affect future instances of Occurrence.

Right now, you have Occurrence taking its start time and end time from Schedule, and you have a one to one relationship between Schedule and Occurrence such that changing Schedule changes all Occurrences.

You should think of Schedule as a template for Occurrence and allow Occurrence to maintain its own start time and end time fields. Those two entities can have the same relationship, but when you query for start time, you query Occurrence and not Schedule. Schedule is only there to provide a "suggested" start and end time.

Denormalization means that Schedule can be edited without affecting old Occurrences, and Occurrences can be individually edited without affecting Schedules or other Occurrences. You get a lot more flexibility for a little more work.

Comment: Is it the right approach to duplicate data from the schedule object like starts_on, duration, type, and possibly more fields in the future like location, room number, capacity, etc. within each occurrence? Also, with your suggested approach, it seems there would be no need for the relationship between occurrence and schedule once the relevant data has been copied.

Comment: Unless you want Schedule and Occurrence tightly coupled the way you currently have them, then some degree of denormalization is necessary to meet your requirements. You could decouple them entirely, but you keep some flexibility by preserving some sort of relationship between them. Consider a case where you want to destroy all Occurrences generated by a given Schedule. Without a relationship, you'd have to create a long query that matches all fields between Schedule and Occurrence. With a relationship, you can simply delete from occurrences where schedule_id = ?

Comment: The problem with having some coupling but still copying is that the schedule could have been completely changed (start time, class type, duration, etc) w.r.t. the past occurrences that are pointing to it. So, if I try to access all occurrences of this new schedule, I will get both the ones before I made the change to this schedule and the ones after. Since I will have to do some extra work anyway, what do you think of creating a new schedule object when the user tries to edit it?

Comment: Why do you even need a Schedule then? You have a Class. It has an Occurrence. 1:1 correspondence. I'm not clear on what maintaining a separate Schedule is buying you at all. This whole time I was thinking that Occurrence *was* the object that described the class... sorry.

Comment: The user sets up a weekly schedule, and rarely needs to change it. This is contained in the schedules table, and modeled by the Schedule class. Now, in a calendar view, we need to show the actual occurrences that are created based on the rules specified in the schedule objects. These occurrences will then have other properties like teacher and students that will not be present in the Schedule class. The user cannot be creating these classes every time. They just specify the rules. But they can change the rules from time to time. It is 1:many correspondence.